# How to get submenu of admin menu?

Tags: menus, admin, sub-menu, globals

I user `global $menu` in one of my plugins to get the list of menu items. But i would like to get the list of of items from a submenu 
for example from `Posts` i would like to get Add new, All, Edit category etc. with slugs or other something unique.

How can i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global variable `$submenu`.

Example to list the child menu of parent post menu:-

```
function admin_init_callback() {
    global $submenu;
    $sumenu_list = $submenu['edit.php'];
    var_dump($sumenu_list); //array of submenu
}
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_init_callback', 999);
```

**Profi660 EDIT:**
Not needed to be used with `admin_init` hook.
I used this in my plugin page and worked very well.